# Servicio requerido pero no encontrado en constructor - service required but not found en constructor

Tags: java, jhipster

Estoy hacienda una App en Jhispter la entidad ExtendedUser tiene una relación de unoAuno con usuario  así que extendí el ExtendedUserDTO para poder guardar los dos al mismo tiempo

Lo raro es que estaba funcionando todo bien, pero ahora tengo este problema.

```
Compilation failure
    [ERROR] /Users/Misael-Mac/Proyectos/sigem/src/test/java/com/gits/sigem/web/rest/UserResourceIntTest.java:[108,37] constructor UserResource in class com.gits.sigem.web.rest.UserResource cannot be applied to given types;
    [ERROR]   required: com.gits.sigem.service.UserService,com.gits.sigem.repository.UserRepository,com.gits.sigem.service.MailService,com.gits.sigem.service.ExtendedUserService
    [ERROR]   found: com.gits.sigem.service.UserService,com.gits.sigem.repository.UserRepository,com.gits.sigem.service.MailService
    [ERROR]   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Lo peor de todo es que aunque regrese al commit anterior el problema persiste, eso quire decir que cometí el error antes de subir mi ultimo commit, fue mucho trabajo y cambios y ahora no encuentro el error.

UserResourseIntTest.java

```
package com.gits.sigem.web.rest;
import ...

/**
 * Test class for the UserResource REST controller.
 *
 * @see UserResource
 */
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = SigemApp.class)
public class UserResourceIntTest {

    private static final String DEFAULT_LOGIN = "johndoe";
    private static final String UPDATED_LOGIN = "jhipster";

    private static final Long DEFAULT_ID = 1L;

    private static final String DEFAULT_PASSWORD = "passjohndoe";
    private static final String UPDATED_PASSWORD = "passjhipster";

    private static final String DEFAULT_EMAIL = "johndoe@localhost";
    private static final String UPDATED_EMAIL = "jhipster@localhost";

    private static final String DEFAULT_FIRSTNAME = "john";
    private static final String UPDATED_FIRSTNAME = "jhipsterFirstName";

    private static final String DEFAULT_LASTNAME = "doe";
    private static final String UPDATED_LASTNAME = "jhipsterLastName";

    private static final String DEFAULT_IMAGEURL = "http://placehold.it/50x50";
    private static final String UPDATED_IMAGEURL = "http://placehold.it/40x40";

    private static final String DEFAULT_LANGKEY = "en";
    private static final String UPDATED_LANGKEY = "fr";

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private MailService mailService;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private UserMapper userMapper;

    @Autowired
    private MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonMessageConverter;

    @Autowired
    private PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver pageableArgumentResolver;

    @Autowired
    private ExceptionTranslator exceptionTranslator;

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager em;

    @Autowired
    private CacheManager cacheManager;

    private MockMvc restUserMockMvc;

    private User user;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        cacheManager.getCache(UserRepository.USERS_BY_LOGIN_CACHE).clear();
        cacheManager.getCache(UserRepository.USERS_BY_EMAIL_CACHE).clear();
        UserResource userResource = new UserResource(userService, userRepository, mailService);
        this.restUserMockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(userResource)
            .setCustomArgumentResolvers(pageableArgumentResolver)
            .setControllerAdvice(exceptionTranslator)
            .setMessageConverters(jacksonMessageConverter)
            .build();
    }


    public static User createEntity(EntityManager em) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setLogin(DEFAULT_LOGIN + RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(5));
        user.setPassword(RandomStringUtils.random(60));
        user.setActivated(true);
        user.setEmail(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(5) + DEFAULT_EMAIL);
        user.setFirstName(DEFAULT_FIRSTNAME);
        user.setLastName(DEFAULT_LASTNAME);
        user.setImageUrl(DEFAULT_IMAGEURL);
        user.setLangKey(DEFAULT_LANGKEY);
        return user;
    }

    @Before
    public void initTest() {
        user = createEntity(em);
        user.setLogin(DEFAULT_LOGIN);
        user.setEmail(DEFAULT_EMAIL);
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void createUser() throws Exception {
        int databaseSizeBeforeCreate = userRepository.findAll().size();

        // Create the User
        ManagedUserVM managedUserVM = new ManagedUserVM();
        managedUserVM.setLogin(DEFAULT_LOGIN);
        managedUserVM.setPassword(DEFAULT_PASSWORD);
        managedUserVM.setFirstName(DEFAULT_FIRSTNAME);
        managedUserVM.setLastName(DEFAULT_LASTNAME);
        managedUserVM.setEmail(DEFAULT_EMAIL);
        managedUserVM.setActivated(true);
        managedUserVM.setImageUrl(DEFAULT_IMAGEURL);
        managedUserVM.setLangKey(DEFAULT_LANGKEY);
        managedUserVM.setAuthorities(Collections.singleton(AuthoritiesConstants.USER));

        restUserMockMvc.perform(post("/api/users")
            .contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(managedUserVM)))
            .andExpect(status().isCreated());

        // Validate the User in the database
        List<User> userList = userRepository.findAll();
        assertThat(userList).hasSize(databaseSizeBeforeCreate + 1);
        User testUser = userList.get(userList.size() - 1);
        assertThat(testUser.getLogin()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_LOGIN);
        assertThat(testUser.getFirstName()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_FIRSTNAME);
        assertThat(testUser.getLastName()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_LASTNAME);
        assertThat(testUser.getEmail()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_EMAIL);
        assertThat(testUser.getImageUrl()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_IMAGEURL);
        assertThat(testUser.getLangKey()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_LANGKEY);
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void createUserWithExistingId() throws Exception {
        int databaseSizeBeforeCreate = userRepository.findAll().size();

        ManagedUserVM managedUserVM = new ManagedUserVM();
        managedUserVM.setId(1L);
        managedUserVM.setLogin(DEFAULT_LOGIN);
        managedUserVM.setPassword(DEFAULT_PASSWORD);
        managedUserVM.setFirstName(DEFAULT_FIRSTNAME);
        managedUserVM.setLastName(DEFAULT_LASTNAME);
        managedUserVM.setEmail(DEFAULT_EMAIL);
        managedUserVM.setActivated(true);
        managedUserVM.setImageUrl(DEFAULT_IMAGEURL);
        managedUserVM.setLangKey(DEFAULT_LANGKEY);
        managedUserVM.setAuthorities(Collections.singleton(AuthoritiesConstants.USER));

        // An entity with an existing ID cannot be created, so this API call must fail
        restUserMockMvc.perform(post("/api/users")
            .contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(managedUserVM)))
            .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());

        // Validate the User in the database
        List<User> userList = userRepository.findAll();
        assertThat(userList).hasSize(databaseSizeBeforeCreate);
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void createUserWithExistingLogin() throws Exception {
        // Initialize the database
        userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);
        int databaseSizeBeforeCreate = userRepository.findAll().size();

        ManagedUserVM managedUserVM = new ManagedUserVM();
        managedUserVM.setLogin(DEFAULT_LOGIN);// this login should already be used
        managedUserVM.setPassword(DEFAULT_PASSWORD);
        managedUserVM.setFirstName(DEFAULT_FIRSTNAME);
        managedUserVM.setLastName(DEFAULT_LASTNAME);
        managedUserVM.setEmail("anothermail@localhost");
        managedUserVM.setActivated(true);
        managedUserVM.setImageUrl(DEFAULT_IMAGEURL);
        managedUserVM.setLangKey(DEFAULT_LANGKEY);
        managedUserVM.setAuthorities(Collections.singleton(AuthoritiesConstants.USER));

        // Create the User
        restUserMockMvc.perform(post("/api/users")
            .contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(managedUserVM)))
            .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());

        // Validate the User in the database
        List<User> userList = userRepository.findAll();
        assertThat(userList).hasSize(databaseSizeBeforeCreate);
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void createUserWithExistingEmail() throws Exception {
        // Initialize the database
        userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);
        int databaseSizeBeforeCreate = userRepository.findAll().size();

        ManagedUserVM managedUserVM = new ManagedUserVM();
        managedUserVM.setLogin("anotherlogin");
        managedUserVM.setPassword(DEFAULT_PASSWORD);
        managedUserVM.setFirstName(DEFAULT_FIRSTNAME);
        managedUserVM.setLastName(DEFAULT_LASTNAME);
        managedUserVM.setEmail(DEFAULT_EMAIL);// this email should already be used
        managedUserVM.setActivated(true);
        managedUserVM.setImageUrl(DEFAULT_IMAGEURL);
        managedUserVM.setLangKey(DEFAULT_LANGKEY);
        managedUserVM.setAuthorities(Collections.singleton(AuthoritiesConstants.USER));

        // Create the User
        restUserMockMvc.perform(post("/api/users")
            .contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(managedUserVM)))
            .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());

        // Validate the User in the database
        List<User> userList = userRepository.findAll();
        assertThat(userList).hasSize(databaseSizeBeforeCreate);
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void getAllUsers() throws Exception {
        // Initialize the database
        userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);

        // Get all the users
        restUserMockMvc.perform(get("/api/users?sort=id,desc")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[*].login").value(hasItem(DEFAULT_LOGIN)))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[*].firstName").value(hasItem(DEFAULT_FIRSTNAME)))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[*].lastName").value(hasItem(DEFAULT_LASTNAME)))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[*].email").value(hasItem(DEFAULT_EMAIL)))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[*].imageUrl").value(hasItem(DEFAULT_IMAGEURL)))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[*].langKey").value(hasItem(DEFAULT_LANGKEY)));
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void getUser() throws Exception {
        // Initialize the database
        userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);

        assertThat(cacheManager.getCache(UserRepository.USERS_BY_LOGIN_CACHE).get(user.getLogin())).isNull();

        // Get the user
        restUserMockMvc.perform(get("/api/users/{login}", user.getLogin()))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.login").value(user.getLogin()))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.firstName").value(DEFAULT_FIRSTNAME))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.lastName").value(DEFAULT_LASTNAME))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.email").value(DEFAULT_EMAIL))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.imageUrl").value(DEFAULT_IMAGEURL))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.langKey").value(DEFAULT_LANGKEY));

        assertThat(cacheManager.getCache(UserRepository.USERS_BY_LOGIN_CACHE).get(user.getLogin())).isNotNull();
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void getNonExistingUser() throws Exception {
        restUserMockMvc.perform(get("/api/users/unknown"))
            .andExpect(status().isNotFound());
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void updateUser() throws Exception {
        // Initialize the database
        userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);
        int databaseSizeBeforeUpdate = userRepository.findAll().size();

        // Update the user
        User updatedUser = userRepository.findById(user.getId()).get();

        ManagedUserVM managedUserVM = new ManagedUserVM();
        managedUserVM.setId(updatedUser.getId());
        managedUserVM.setLogin(updatedUser.getLogin());
        managedUserVM.setPassword(UPDATED_PASSWORD);
        managedUserVM.setFirstName(UPDATED_FIRSTNAME);
        managedUserVM.setLastName(UPDATED_LASTNAME);
        managedUserVM.setEmail(UPDATED_EMAIL);
        managedUserVM.setActivated(updatedUser.getActivated());
        managedUserVM.setImageUrl(UPDATED_IMAGEURL);
        managedUserVM.setLangKey(UPDATED_LANGKEY);
        managedUserVM.setCreatedBy(updatedUser.getCreatedBy());
        managedUserVM.setCreatedDate(updatedUser.getCreatedDate());
        managedUserVM.setLastModifiedBy(updatedUser.getLastModifiedBy());
        managedUserVM.setLastModifiedDate(updatedUser.getLastModifiedDate());
        managedUserVM.setAuthorities(Collections.singleton(AuthoritiesConstants.USER));

        restUserMockMvc.perform(put("/api/users")
            .contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(managedUserVM)))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());

        // Validate the User in the database
        List<User> userList = userRepository.findAll();
        assertThat(userList).hasSize(databaseSizeBeforeUpdate);
        User testUser = userList.get(userList.size() - 1);
        assertThat(testUser.getFirstName()).isEqualTo(UPDATED_FIRSTNAME);
        assertThat(testUser.getLastName()).isEqualTo(UPDATED_LASTNAME);
        assertThat(testUser.getEmail()).isEqualTo(UPDATED_EMAIL);
        assertThat(testUser.getImageUrl()).isEqualTo(UPDATED_IMAGEURL);
        assertThat(testUser.getLangKey()).isEqualTo(UPDATED_LANGKEY);
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void updateUserLogin() throws Exception {
        // Initialize the database
        userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);
        int databaseSizeBeforeUpdate = userRepository.findAll().size();

        // Update the user
        User updatedUser = userRepository.findById(user.getId()).get();

        ManagedUserVM managedUserVM = new ManagedUserVM();
        managedUserVM.setId(updatedUser.getId());
        managedUserVM.setLogin(UPDATED_LOGIN);
        managedUserVM.setPassword(UPDATED_PASSWORD);
        managedUserVM.setFirstName(UPDATED_FIRSTNAME);
        managedUserVM.setLastName(UPDATED_LASTNAME);
        managedUserVM.setEmail(UPDATED_EMAIL);
        managedUserVM.setActivated(updatedUser.getActivated());
        managedUserVM.setImageUrl(UPDATED_IMAGEURL);
        managedUserVM.setLangKey(UPDATED_LANGKEY);
        managedUserVM.setCreatedBy(updatedUser.getCreatedBy());
        managedUserVM.setCreatedDate(updatedUser.getCreatedDate());
        managedUserVM.setLastModifiedBy(updatedUser.getLastModifiedBy());
        managedUserVM.setLastModifiedDate(updatedUser.getLastModifiedDate());
        managedUserVM.setAuthorities(Collections.singleton(AuthoritiesConstants.USER));

        restUserMockMvc.perform(put("/api/users")
            .contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(managedUserVM)))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());

        // Validate the User in the database
        List<User> userList = userRepository.findAll();
        assertThat(userList).hasSize(databaseSizeBeforeUpdate);
        User testUser = userList.get(userList.size() - 1);
        assertThat(testUser.getLogin()).isEqualTo(UPDATED_LOGIN);
        assertThat(testUser.getFirstName()).isEqualTo(UPDATED_FIRSTNAME);
        assertThat(testUser.getLastName()).isEqualTo(UPDATED_LASTNAME);
        assertThat(testUser.getEmail()).isEqualTo(UPDATED_EMAIL);
        assertThat(testUser.getImageUrl()).isEqualTo(UPDATED_IMAGEURL);
        assertThat(testUser.getLangKey()).isEqualTo(UPDATED_LANGKEY);
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void updateUserExistingEmail() throws Exception {
        // Initialize the database with 2 users
        userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);

        User anotherUser = new User();
        anotherUser.setLogin("jhipster");
        anotherUser.setPassword(RandomStringUtils.random(60));
        anotherUser.setActivated(true);
        anotherUser.setEmail("jhipster@localhost");
        anotherUser.setFirstName("java");
        anotherUser.setLastName("hipster");
        anotherUser.setImageUrl("");
        anotherUser.setLangKey("en");
        userRepository.saveAndFlush(anotherUser);

        // Update the user
        User updatedUser = userRepository.findById(user.getId()).get();

        ManagedUserVM managedUserVM = new ManagedUserVM();
        managedUserVM.setId(updatedUser.getId());
        managedUserVM.setLogin(updatedUser.getLogin());
        managedUserVM.setPassword(updatedUser.getPassword());
        managedUserVM.setFirstName(updatedUser.getFirstName());
        managedUserVM.setLastName(updatedUser.getLastName());
        managedUserVM.setEmail("jhipster@localhost");// this email should already be used by anotherUser
        managedUserVM.setActivated(updatedUser.getActivated());
        managedUserVM.setImageUrl(updatedUser.getImageUrl());
        managedUserVM.setLangKey(updatedUser.getLangKey());
        managedUserVM.setCreatedBy(updatedUser.getCreatedBy());
        managedUserVM.setCreatedDate(updatedUser.getCreatedDate());
        managedUserVM.setLastModifiedBy(updatedUser.getLastModifiedBy());
        managedUserVM.setLastModifiedDate(updatedUser.getLastModifiedDate());
        managedUserVM.setAuthorities(Collections.singleton(AuthoritiesConstants.USER));

        restUserMockMvc.perform(put("/api/users")
            .contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(managedUserVM)))
            .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void updateUserExistingLogin() throws Exception {
        // Initialize the database
        userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);

        User anotherUser = new User();
        anotherUser.setLogin("jhipster");
        anotherUser.setPassword(RandomStringUtils.random(60));
        anotherUser.setActivated(true);
        anotherUser.setEmail("jhipster@localhost");
        anotherUser.setFirstName("java");
        anotherUser.setLastName("hipster");
        anotherUser.setImageUrl("");
        anotherUser.setLangKey("en");
        userRepository.saveAndFlush(anotherUser);

        // Update the user
        User updatedUser = userRepository.findById(user.getId()).get();

        ManagedUserVM managedUserVM = new ManagedUserVM();
        managedUserVM.setId(updatedUser.getId());
        managedUserVM.setLogin("jhipster");// this login should already be used by anotherUser
        managedUserVM.setPassword(updatedUser.getPassword());
        managedUserVM.setFirstName(updatedUser.getFirstName());
        managedUserVM.setLastName(updatedUser.getLastName());
        managedUserVM.setEmail(updatedUser.getEmail());
        managedUserVM.setActivated(updatedUser.getActivated());
        managedUserVM.setImageUrl(updatedUser.getImageUrl());
        managedUserVM.setLangKey(updatedUser.getLangKey());
        managedUserVM.setCreatedBy(updatedUser.getCreatedBy());
        managedUserVM.setCreatedDate(updatedUser.getCreatedDate());
        managedUserVM.setLastModifiedBy(updatedUser.getLastModifiedBy());
        managedUserVM.setLastModifiedDate(updatedUser.getLastModifiedDate());
        managedUserVM.setAuthorities(Collections.singleton(AuthoritiesConstants.USER));

        restUserMockMvc.perform(put("/api/users")
            .contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(managedUserVM)))
            .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void deleteUser() throws Exception {
        // Initialize the database
        userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);
        int databaseSizeBeforeDelete = userRepository.findAll().size();

        // Delete the user
        restUserMockMvc.perform(delete("/api/users/{login}", user.getLogin())
            .accept(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());

        assertThat(cacheManager.getCache(UserRepository.USERS_BY_LOGIN_CACHE).get(user.getLogin())).isNull();

        // Validate the database is empty
        List<User> userList = userRepository.findAll();
        assertThat(userList).hasSize(databaseSizeBeforeDelete - 1);
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void getAllAuthorities() throws Exception {
        restUserMockMvc.perform(get("/api/users/authorities")
            .accept(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$").isArray())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$").value(containsInAnyOrder(AuthoritiesConstants.USER, AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)));
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void testUserEquals() throws Exception {
        TestUtil.equalsVerifier(User.class);
        User user1 = new User();
        user1.setId(1L);
        User user2 = new User();
        user2.setId(user1.getId());
        assertThat(user1).isEqualTo(user2);
        user2.setId(2L);
        assertThat(user1).isNotEqualTo(user2);
        user1.setId(null);
        assertThat(user1).isNotEqualTo(user2);
    }

    @Test
    public void testUserFromId() {
        assertThat(userMapper.userFromId(DEFAULT_ID).getId()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_ID);
        assertThat(userMapper.userFromId(null)).isNull();
    }

    @Test
    public void testUserDTOtoUser() {
        UserDTO userDTO = new UserDTO();
        userDTO.setId(DEFAULT_ID);
        userDTO.setLogin(DEFAULT_LOGIN);
        userDTO.setFirstName(DEFAULT_FIRSTNAME);
        userDTO.setLastName(DEFAULT_LASTNAME);
        userDTO.setEmail(DEFAULT_EMAIL);
        userDTO.setActivated(true);
        userDTO.setImageUrl(DEFAULT_IMAGEURL);
        userDTO.setLangKey(DEFAULT_LANGKEY);
        userDTO.setCreatedBy(DEFAULT_LOGIN);
        userDTO.setLastModifiedBy(DEFAULT_LOGIN);
        userDTO.setAuthorities(Collections.singleton(AuthoritiesConstants.USER));

        User user = userMapper.userDTOToUser(userDTO);
        assertThat(user.getId()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_ID);
        assertThat(user.getLogin()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_LOGIN);
        assertThat(user.getFirstName()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_FIRSTNAME);
        assertThat(user.getLastName()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_LASTNAME);
        assertThat(user.getEmail()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_EMAIL);
        assertThat(user.getActivated()).isEqualTo(true);
        assertThat(user.getImageUrl()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_IMAGEURL);
        assertThat(user.getLangKey()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_LANGKEY);
        assertThat(user.getCreatedBy()).isNull();
        assertThat(user.getCreatedDate()).isNotNull();
        assertThat(user.getLastModifiedBy()).isNull();
        assertThat(user.getLastModifiedDate()).isNotNull();
        assertThat(user.getAuthorities()).extracting("name").containsExactly(AuthoritiesConstants.USER);
    }

    @Test
    public void testUserToUserDTO() {
        user.setId(DEFAULT_ID);
        user.setCreatedBy(DEFAULT_LOGIN);
        user.setCreatedDate(Instant.now());
        user.setLastModifiedBy(DEFAULT_LOGIN);
        user.setLastModifiedDate(Instant.now());
        Set<Authority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
        Authority authority = new Authority();
        authority.setName(AuthoritiesConstants.USER);
        authorities.add(authority);
        user.setAuthorities(authorities);

        UserDTO userDTO = userMapper.userToUserDTO(user);

        assertThat(userDTO.getId()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_ID);
        assertThat(userDTO.getLogin()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_LOGIN);
        assertThat(userDTO.getFirstName()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_FIRSTNAME);
        assertThat(userDTO.getLastName()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_LASTNAME);
        assertThat(userDTO.getEmail()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_EMAIL);
        assertThat(userDTO.isActivated()).isEqualTo(true);
        assertThat(userDTO.getImageUrl()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_IMAGEURL);
        assertThat(userDTO.getLangKey()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_LANGKEY);
        assertThat(userDTO.getCreatedBy()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_LOGIN);
        assertThat(userDTO.getCreatedDate()).isEqualTo(user.getCreatedDate());
        assertThat(userDTO.getLastModifiedBy()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_LOGIN);
        assertThat(userDTO.getLastModifiedDate()).isEqualTo(user.getLastModifiedDate());
        assertThat(userDTO.getAuthorities()).containsExactly(AuthoritiesConstants.USER);
        assertThat(userDTO.toString()).isNotNull();
    }

    @Test
    public void testAuthorityEquals() throws Exception {
        Authority authorityA = new Authority();
        assertThat(authorityA).isEqualTo(authorityA);
        assertThat(authorityA).isNotEqualTo(null);
        assertThat(authorityA).isNotEqualTo(new Object());
        assertThat(authorityA.hashCode()).isEqualTo(0);
        assertThat(authorityA.toString()).isNotNull();

        Authority authorityB = new Authority();
        assertThat(authorityA).isEqualTo(authorityB);

        authorityB.setName(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN);
        assertThat(authorityA).isNotEqualTo(authorityB);

        authorityA.setName(AuthoritiesConstants.USER);
        assertThat(authorityA).isNotEqualTo(authorityB);

        authorityB.setName(AuthoritiesConstants.USER);
        assertThat(authorityA).isEqualTo(authorityB);
        assertThat(authorityA.hashCode()).isEqualTo(authorityB.hashCode());
    }
}
```

**Actualización** 
ok, esto se puso mas raro, cuando estaba buscando UserResourseIntTest.java vi que ya estaba compilando y ahora funciona bien de nuevo ‍♂️.

Estoy usando IntelliJ IDEA en una MacBook Air

Este es el código que fallaba claramente si faltaba que pasara un parámetro, pero ahora otra vez funciona  y no eh movido nada yo.

UserResourseIntTest.java:

```
  @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        cacheManager.getCache(UserRepository.USERS_BY_LOGIN_CACHE).clear();
        cacheManager.getCache(UserRepository.USERS_BY_EMAIL_CACHE).clear();
        UserResource userResource = new UserResource(userService, userRepository, mailService);
        this.restUserMockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(userResource)
            .setCustomArgumentResolvers(pageableArgumentResolver)
            .setControllerAdvice(exceptionTranslator)
            .setMessageConverters(jacksonMessageConverter)
            .build();
    }
```

Comment: puedes agregar la clase UserResourceIntTest.java? en algun lado del test estas instanciando el object y en su constructor estas pasandole difrentes parametros..

Comment: Okay permiteme explicarte, en java los IDE Integrated Development Environment que en espaniol quiere decir entorno de desarrollo integrado generan folders desde el src/ que significa source osea origen  luego viene el  main/ o el test/ donde el main esel folder principal del codigo y el test es el folder para hacer tus pruebas en base a lo que tienes en tu main

Comment: @JonathanJohx ahora ya funciona bien no sé si necesitaba actualizarse o limpiar cache(?) igual mi mac tiene ya poco espacio y ram

Comment: OK bro, If you have some question related with spring-boot/java/Jpa/Hibernate, let me know it. johxgks@gmail.com kind regards. @MisaelLanderos

Comment: @JonathanJohx thank you, you are great !  

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cómo comente estoy empezando con Jhipster, ahora se que Jhipster crea un test para verificar si hubo cambios importantes así que el error no estaba en **UserResourse.java** si no en **UserResourseIntTest.java**, que esta en otra carpeta.

Así que tuve que importar el user service y añadirlo en la lista de parámetros.

```
private ExtendedUserService extendedUserService;
...
...
UserResource userResource = new UserResource(userService, userRepository, mailService, extendedUserService);
```

Con eso ya se resuelve el error.